# 3D point from a know point, distance, angle.

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d

Let's assume I have a point in 3D space A(x,y,z).
Two points of distance 'd' from that point A with angle $\alpha$ (with XY plane), $\beta$ (with XZ plane).What are those two points ?

[image]

Comment: not quite sure what you mean by point with angle

Comment: I am adding an image, give me few seconds

Comment: i have edited,please see

Comment: Haha, that truly is a "bad image" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the point you're interested in be $(a,b,c)$. Now, this point is distance $d$ from $A$. You get the first equation:

$$(a-x)^2+(b-y)^2+(c-z)^2=d^2$$

Also, it seems the position vector of this point has an angle $\alpha$ with the x-y plane, meaning $\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha$ with the z-axis. So the second equation:

$$\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha) = \frac{c}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$
$$=> a^2+b^2+c^2 = c \tan(\alpha)$$

Similarly, the third equation becomes:

$$\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta) = \frac{b}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$
$$=>a^2+b^2+c^2=b\tan(\beta)$$

This makes it three equations in three unknowns ($a,b,c$). It's a system of quadratic equations. One way to solve them would be to use Buchberger's algorithm, which can solve an arbitrary system of Polynomial equations. See section 2.7 [here](https://doc.lagout.org/science/0_Computer%20Science/2_Algorithms/Ideals%2C%20Varieties%2C%20and%20Algorithms%20%284th%20ed.%29%20%5BCox%2C%20Little%20%26%20O%27Shea%202015-06-14%5D.pdf) and the python package, sympy implements it. See [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Quick-examples) section on solving polynomial equations. Although I'd recommend the python library, I also implemented this algorithm in C# a while back. See [here](https://github.com/ryu577/GroebnerBasis).

Comment: thanks for this great help, you are just awesome. i can't tell how much this was for me.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: i can't up-vote, but i accepted it, i wish i could